# Milliseconds out of sync

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a stopwatch application using Javascript/jQuery. The problem is that the milliseconds value is out of sync with `REAL` milliseconds. I am using function `setInterval()` with the interval of `1 millisecond`, still it is causing this problem.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FLv3s/

Please help!

Comment: setInternal will only guarantee the minimum time to wait, it could be more

Comment: Do you really believe that code is executed in under 1ms every millisecond? I suggest you set the interval to e.g. 20ms and get the time including milliseconds from a Date object.

Comment: How do you know that each millisecond++ that you make, takes only 1 millisecond? That's wrong logic. Use system's own time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `setInterval` to trigger updates, but use the system time (via `new Date()`) for the actual time calculations.

Comment: which will also not be 100% accurate :) i.e: you might stop the whatch while setInterval was processing the new Date() on it's own rate, and on the screen you'll get a different result than in the *real world*.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: Whenever you start or stop the watch, you update your time calculation.  You don't just leave it displaying whatever it had calculated at the most recent timer tick.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I tried nearly the same thing as you do now (Creating an accurate Metronome in Javascript only) - to make a long story short: To be absolutely accurate in terms of milliseconds (or lower) is sadly not (yet) possible with javascript only.

For more insight i recommend this question: [Does JavaScript provide a high resolution timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875625/does-javascript-provide-a-high-resolution-timer)

or to be more precise this blog article: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Best regards,
Dominik

Answer (score 1):

Program execution in any language, not just JavaScript, is not realtime. It will take a tiny amount of time to actually run the code to increment your counter and update the view, and that throws the "timing" off.

Additionally, many browsers have a "minimum timeout" length, which varies between 4 and about 16 (the latter being the computer's own clock timer), which will really mess with your code.

Instead, you should use *delta timing*.

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
setInterval(function() {
    var elapsed = new Date().getTime()-startTime;
    // update view according to elapsed time
},25);
```

If you're worried about it looking choppy, consider using `requestAnimationFrame` instead, to update the timer exactly once per frame - this has the added benefit of not updating when the user switches tabs (but it will still be timing them) because if the tab is not active then there's no need to redraw stuff.

Comment: Why did you set the interval as 25? (Sorry for the terribly late reply!)

Comment: A 25ms interval corresponds to 40fps, which is more than fast enough for most applications. You can set it to any number you want really. Lower numbers are more precise but consume more CPU resources, whereas higher numbers are more CPU-friendly but less immediate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new `performance` object to get a more accurate time. Combine this with `requestAnimationFrame` instead of setInterval:

```
var startTime = performance.now(),
    currentTime,
    isRunning = true;

loop();

function loop(timeElapsed) {

    currentTime = performance.now();
    if (isRunning) requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

Just subtract `startTime` from `currentTime`.

I left `timeElapsed` which contains time elapsed handed by rAF which you can may use also for something (or just ignore it).

One note though: not all browsers support this yet (and some may use prefix) so for mobile you need to use the standard system time object.

Comment: I googled but didnt find any documentation on the `performance` object.

Comment: @IamDesai just open console in f.ex.Chrome and start typing performance.. You can for example use `performance.now()`