# How to pass a variable from one require() to another?

Tags: dojo

I have a variable currently set globally, that I am using in two different `require()` functions. How can I have it passed from first `require()` to the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know: you don't. The only way to make them read the same data is by putting it somewhere so they both can read it. Because both `require()` functions are placed inside a normal JavaScript file, the only scope they share is the global scope.

The other possibility is by passing it to the callback function of the `require()`, but that means you have to write a "module" that returns your data (or use `dojo/text` plugin to read a file read-only).

It's not recommended to have two `require()` statements at all. If we're still talking about the same stopwatch (I've read your code a bit), you should put all event handlers in one `require()` block. Then you can put the data they both need inside that `require()` block and they will all be able to read it.

Some reasons why having multiple `require()` blocks is not beneficial:

- **Harder to read/maintain**: If you have multiple `require()` blocks, it's confusing. Most people don't use it anyways (recommended or not).
- **More duplicates**: If you're using common modules like `dojo/query` and `dojo/dom`, you will have to add them to your module list every time. I don't think it will download the file twice, but it's still more to write/maintain.
- **Scope issues**: As you just noticed, you will have scoping issues like this when multiple `require()` blocks needs to access the same data. This means you have to put them in global scope (which is another bad practice), write a module with just plain data (not really useful) or you have to wrap both of them in a function, which you have to execute manually (confusing)
- **Seperation concerns**: If you have a valid reason to seperate them, you should be seperating them into modules.

Comment: Why is it not recommended to have two `require()` statements?

Comment: For reasons like this, because it's confusing to read, lots of duplicate things you need to write (like common module imports such as `dojo/query`), harder to maintain and above all there must be something wrong in your design if you want to do that. If you seperate `require()` blocks, I suppose you have a reason to seperate them, if you have a valid reason you should be defining seperate modules in stead.

Comment: Looks like your stopwatch is improved a lot. I was already thinking it might never work by adding an interval of 1ms, your browser wouldn't be able to handle that ;)

Comment: I have now set it to 25ms as per  Niet's suggestion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973048/milliseconds-out-of-sync/19973169?noredirect=1#comment31598257_19973169

Comment: Can you help me with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678477/how-to-search-in-2-columns-with-single-search-box