# How to search in 2 columns with single search box?

Tags: javascript, dojo

In my project, I would like to find by name and email in the dgrid. As of now, I am able to search by name only. I used the following:

```
dgrid.set("query", {name: new RegExp(searchKeyword, 'i')});
```

How do I modify this so that I can search by both, name AND email?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/F5HFY/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The querying engine behind a `dojo/store/Memory` (called [`dojo/store/util/SimpleQueryEngine`](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store/util/SimpleQueryEngine.html)) does not support **OR** operations, which means it can't query all records where:

```
name matches searchterm OR email matches searchterm
```

To solve that issue you will have to use a different query engine than the default one. Currently there are no other query engines available in Dojo but there is a standalone project called the resource query language. You should check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12227056/1915448) and the library itself on [Github](https://github.com/kriszyp/rql).

Answer (score 1):

You try to input two parameter in single textbox and want to search result according to that. It is up to you, how you create logic, I tried something hope this will help you.

I have made some alteration in your code so I am explaining what I done only. Here I uesd comma to separate two search value.

```
var keywordArr = searchKeyword.split(','); // separate search values by comma
var len = keywordArr.length; 
var query = {}; // search object

if(len>1){ // check whether there is two value or single
  query.name = keywordArr[0];
  if(validateEmail(keywordArr[1])){
    query.email = keywordArr[1];
  } 
} else { // if single value then
  if(validateEmail(searchKeyword)){ // check whether is it email or not
    query.email = searchKeyword;                   
  } else {
    query.name = new RegExp(searchKeyword, 'i');
  }                                                                 
}
dgrid.set("query", query); // search query

// function to validate email id
function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(email);
}
```

You can try my code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkr9/F5HFY/9/).
Thank you

Comment: but I have test it the code is working I have tested it with input 3 times on 1st rahul, 2nd rahuldesai209@gmail.com and on 3rd both rahul and rahuldesai209@gmail.com and it gives me result.

Comment: do one thing replace `dgrid.set("query", {name: new RegExp(searchKeyword, 'i')});` with my code

Comment: can you provide me jsFiddle url where you apply this code?

Comment: I just replace `query.name = keywordArr[0];` with `query.name = new RegExp(keywordArr[0],'i');`
testing parameter as
`rahul --> result single row`
`rahuldesai209@gmail.com --> single row`
`rahul,rahuldesai209@gmail.com --> single row`
`nilesh,rahuldesai209@gmail.com --> No results found`

Comment: Hey bro I have test this (http://jsfiddle.net/mkr9/F5HFY/9/) on different system and its working fine

Comment: Sorry dude. I checked on Chrome v30 and Firefox v28. Doesnt work. :( I can search by `name` but not by `email`.

Comment: I don't know where issue is creating, I explaining you logic what I try to do is, I use comma to separate both name and email input from search text box. Then perform some validation test and then create an object contain name and email like `query = {name:'Mithles',email:'naveen@gmail.com'}` and pass it as `dgrid.set('query',query)`, it will search data according to both value and return result. This is what I implemented

Comment: Ah, now I understand your implementation (I didnt knew you are seperating the inputs by a comma). Actually, the way I would like to implement this is to have a single input (no comma separated, nothing - just a singlw word) and this single input would search the dgrid in both `name` and `email` columns. Got it?

Comment: Yes I got your point, but still there is two case
1) both `name` and `email` apply together so that result will contain both `name` and `email` match like `name AND email` where we get search value in both `name` and `email`.
2) first result will get by `name` and then `email` and show combined result like `name OR email` where we get search value either in `name` or `email`;

Comment: Let us say, the search keyword should match either `name` OR `email`. How do we do this?

Comment: for this you have to filter data manually for both and then merge them and set store of dgrid on every search otherwise you have to hack dgrid's store to implement new logic for store query.