# getting delayed value using javascript Date.now()

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, web-worker

output of this code is always getting delayed by 25-30 milliseconds. Why?

i tried same using [Webworker](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp), even then output was delayed.
How to fix this issue?

I want almost perfect output for the following code.

```js
var j = 0;
var start = Date.now();
setInterval(function() {
  j++;
  if (j % 10 == 0) {
    var end = Date.now();
    console.log(end - start);
  }

}, 50);
```

[image]

Comment: What's your final use-case? (I suspect `console.log` isn't it...)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript intervals does not guarantee that the function is called at the exact time, just that it is called "sometime after" the amount of time specified.

[This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) explains a bit about window.performance timing which you might be able to use, depending on what browsers you need to support. You can look at the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875625/does-javascript-provide-a-high-resolution-timer) for some code examples.