# jQuery Timer and sound not sync'd

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I built a page where a user can input a value in seconds, and then a ping will sound at that interval.  I also put together a timer, that should be in sync with the ping intervals.  Like if they input 5 - the clock should be running past 5, 10, 15 ect... when the ping is sounding.  For a reason I can't figure out, the sound doesn't seem to quite be sync'd with the clock and it gets worse the longer it's been running.  Thanks for your help!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#set_ping').click(function() {
    interval = parseInt($('#ping_val').val()*1000,10);
    $('#ping_alert').text('The ping will sound every ' + interval/1000 + ' seconds.');
  });

  $('#go').click(function() {  
    timer();
    setInterval(sound, interval);

   });

  function sound() {
   $('#audio').append('<embed src="assets/audio/sound88.mp3" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="false">');    
  }

  var seconds = 0;
  function timer() {setInterval(function() {
    $('#progress').text(seconds++/100);
  }, 10);
 }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just embed it, do not set autoplay, set it to preload, and call it to play with JavaScript. beats appending the element every time.

Answer (score 0):

It's because [timers in JavaScript are not exactly that accurate](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/12/14/timer-resolution-in-browsers/). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/196138/575527) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13089677/575527) as well. Also, due to the fact that JavaScript is single-threaded, timers only execute when nothing else is executing. If your page is busy, stuff that are actually "scheduled" to execute get "delayed" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code from bellow:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var interval;
  $('#set_ping').click(function() {
    interval = parseInt($('#ping_val').val()*1000,10);
    $('#ping_alert').text('The ping will sound every ' + interval/1000 + ' seconds.');
  });

  $('#go').click(function() {  
    timer();
    setInterval(sound, interval);

   });

  function sound() {
   $('#audio').append('<embed src="assets/audio/sound88.mp3" autostart="true"     hidden="true" loop="false">');    
  }

  var seconds = 0;
  function timer() {setInterval(function() {
    $('#progress').text(seconds++/100);
    if(seconds % interval == 0){
       // play music here 
    } 
  }, 10);
 }
});
```

In that code when code update the time it also check if the time (Your `seconds` variable) if multiple of `interval` variable with holds the time interval betweens sounds.
Note `interval` is global variable