# Keeping microsecond precision when passing datetime between django and javascript

Tags: javascript, django, time, precision

It seems django, or the sqlite database, is storing datetimes with microsecond precision. However when [passing a time to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455580/json-datetime-between-python-and-javascript) the `Date` object only supports milliseconds:

```
var stringFromDjango = "2015-08-01 01:24:58.520124+10:00";
var time = new Date(stringFromDjango);
$('#time_field').val(time.toISOString()); //"2015-07-31T15:24:58.520Z"
```

Note the `58.520124` is now `58.520`.

This becomes an issue when, for example, I want to create a queryset for all objects with a datetime less than or equal to the time of an existing object (i.e. `MyModel.objects.filter(time__lte=javascript_datetime)`). By truncating the microseconds the object no longer appears in the list as the time is not equal.

How can I work around this? Is there a datetime javascript object that supports microsecond accuracy? Can I truncate times in the database to milliseconds (I'm pretty much using [`auto_now_add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) everywhere) or ask that the query be performed with reduced accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I work around this?

TL;DR: Store less precision, either by:

- Coaxing your DB platform to store only miliseconds and discard any additional precision (difficult on SQLite, I think)
- Only ever inserting values with the precision you want (difficult to ensure you've covered all cases)

> Is there a datetime javascript object that supports microsecond accuracy?

If you encode your dates as Strings or Numbers you can add however much accuracy you'd like. There are other options (some discussed [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233927/microsecond-timing-in-javascript)). Unless you actually *want* this accuracy though, it's probably not the best approach.

> Can I truncate times in the database to milliseconds..

Yes, but because you're on SQLite it's a bit weird. SQLite doesn't really have dates; you're actually storing the values in either a `text`, `real` or `integer` field. These underlying storage classes dictate the precision and range of the values you can store. There's a decent [write up of the differences here](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-date/).

You could, for example, change your underlying storage class to `integer`. This would truncate dates stored in that field to a precision of 1 second. When performing your queries from JS, you could likewise truncate your dates using the [`Date.prototype.setMilliseconds()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMilliseconds). Eg..

```
MyModel.objects.filter(time__lte = javascript_datetime.setMilliseconds(0))
```

A more feature complete DB platform would handle it better. For example in PostgreSQL you can [specify the precision stored more exactly](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-datetime.html). This will add a timestamp column with precision down to miliseconds (matching that of Javascript)..

```
alter table "my_table" add "my_timestamp" timestamp (3) with time zone
```

MySQL will [let you do the same thing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fractional-seconds.html).

> .. or ask that the query be performed with reduced accuracy?

Yeah but this is usually the wrong approach.

If the criteria you're filtering *by* is to precise then you're ok; you can truncate the value then filter (like in the `..setMilliseconds()` example above). But if the values in the DB you're checking *against* are too precise you're going to have a Bad Time.

You *could* write a query such that the stored values are formatted or truncated to reduce their precision before being compared to your criteria but that operation is going to need to be performed **for every value stored**. This could be millions of values. What's more, because you're generating the values dynamically, you've just circumvented any indexes created against the stored values.