# javascript date equality confusion

Tags: javascript

I have two dates who are equal when new Date is used but their getTime()'s are different.

Here are both dates:

```
1) Wed Nov 25 2015 08:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST) 
2) Wed Nov 25 2015 08:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

Their getTime()'s are:

```
1) 1448456400924 
2) 1448456400000
```

Off by a small amount, What is the cause of this? I've used both setSeconds(0) and setMinutes(0) on one date, the logs are what you see.

Comment: JavaScript dates have a millisecond precision...

Comment: how do you create the dates ?

Comment: Juhana thanks thats probably it. That was it upvoted your comment. Thanks again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233927/microsecond-timing-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Javascript Dates have millisecond precision:** *The getTime() method returns the number of milliseconds between midnight of January 1, 1970 and the specified date.*

```
var date = new Date().setMilliseconds(0)
```

The last 3 digits are the issue, and the above code would correct `1448456400924` to `1448456400000` as an example.