# Microsecond or at least sub-millisecond timing in a web-worker?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

There are libraries for high precision timers in `node.js` and there is the `window.performance.now()` for the main thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/21120901/1056563. Is there anything for web-workers (which do not have access to `window` or the `DOM`)?

Comment: Some contexts support `WorkerGlobalScope.performance` but not all browsers

Comment: That's a reasonable answer: please add and I'll award

Comment: Would the down–voter care to explain their vote? It seems like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: Yea this is a clear question with a simple answer, it's not (to me) a request for a library or resource etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `performance` property on `WorkerGlobalScope`. It's not super-widely supported, but then again neither are web workers.

Specifically, `.now()` is (apparently) available to web workers, if that's all you need.

Comment: From this looks like we get `chrome` but not `safari`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/performance

Comment: Yes also probably some mobile browsers and almost certainly IE11.

Comment: "neither are web workers" A feature having support from IE10+ can now be called *widely supported*. And in MDN the `?` doesn't mean it's not supported, just taht the ones maintaining the support table didn't check. Safari does support performance.now in a Worker.

Comment: @Kalido fair enough, the MDN support thing is as you say indeterminate. Still, if I were creating a web application I would certainly plan on some kind of fallback if the `.performance` property weren't there.

Comment: Yeah, more importantly, and I forgot to mention that in my previous comment, performance.now lost a great deal of precision because of meltdown and spectre.